# Error in Installing Rails Using DevKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

Im trying to install rails using Devkit on windows 7

I have installed railsinstaller

I added the path to Ruby2.1.0 in config.yml:

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0
```

When ever I try to run

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

It gives me the following :

> [INFO] Skipping existing gem override for
>   'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0'
>   [WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper
>   library for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0'

When I tried to use force option:

```
ruby dk.rb install --force
```

I get this :

> [WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for
>   'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2 .1.0' [WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit
>   helper library for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2 .1.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered other stack overflow questions similarly. Like here:

[warnings being treated as errors in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901627/warnings-being-treated-as-errors-in-rails/29901755#29901755)

But my honest suggestion is to nip your rails development in the bud, and start developing on OSX or Linux. You will be very grateful that you did. Ruby is very naturally linuxy in nature, and getting out of a windows environment will help save you a lot of heart and head ache.

I recommend using the Vagrant virtual machine on windows for Ruby development. Vagrant runs linux ubuntu and allows you to sync folders between your local machine and your virtual machine. Documentation and instructions are here:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html

Of course, if you have access to a mac, OSX comes preinstalled with Ruby, so it should take only minutes to get your Rails environment ready to go. If you don't, Vagrant is a great virtual machine to run with.